# Proprietary Software Friendly Computer Algebra Library in C/C++

Tags: library, c++, math, c

I'm looking into developing some proprietary software that involves Fields, Linear Algebra over Fields, Rings, Groups,...

Speed of execution is very important, which is why I'm looking to develop in C/C++.

I've found a few maintained computer algebra libraries that would work (GiNac, SymbolicC++) but these are released under GPL. Thus I would have to release my software under GPL if I used these tools.

Does anyone know of a computer algebra system in C/C++ that is licensed under MIT/BSD/... or some other proprietary license? Cost isn't really a concern yet.